# Want to display a gap between a line

Tags: html

I want to split a single straight line into 2 lines, something as below. What is the best way to achieve it?

I am trying to use hr element but couldn't split the line.

---

Comment: I need lines like below:                                                                                _____________________                                ___________________

Answer (score 1):

there you can actually do that using pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after`

```css
.line {
  position: relative;
}

.line::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 45%;
  /* change the with based on your need */
  left: 0;
}

.line::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 45%;
  /* change the with based on your need */
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: you are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- change the 8px to what ever gap value you want-->
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 8px 1fr">
<hr style="width: 100%"/>
<div></div>
<hr  style="width: 100%"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this!

```css
.line-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.line {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 150px;
}

#line-2 {
  margin-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-wrapper">
  <div class="line" id="line-1">

  </div>

  <div class="line" id="line-2">

  </div>
</div>
```